# In Corona SDK is it possible to use Scenes for a view that partially overlays another view

Tags: coronasdk

I have a Settings view that I want to slide over my main game view, but only partially, so that the main view is still visible behind the Settings view (a bit like a modal dialog)
The main game view would then be darkened (or blurred) slightly so its obvious that its not active anymore.

Is it possible to use a Scene to achieve this effect?  I would really prefer to keep the code for the Settings view separated from the code for the main view.  If not Scenes, then any other suggestions or examples I can look at.

Comment: I would like to use Storyboard if possible, rather than Director Class (which is no longer being supported)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it working using the following code in the tap event handler for the button in the source view:

```
local options =
{
    effect = "zoomOutIn",
    time = 200,
    isModal = true,
}
storyboard.showOverlay( "scenes.settings", options )
```

Using isModal=true prevents any clicks on the overlay view from propagating down onto the original view which remains displayed underneath the overlay view.  Here is a tutorial explaining how to create an overlay view:
http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/04/27/scene-overlays-and-parameter-passing/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. I'll give you a sample:

**-- main.lua --**

```
local storyboard = require "storyboard"
storyboard.gotoScene( "scene1", "fade", 400 )
```

**-- settings.lua --**

```
local function myObject(group,x,y,imagePath)

  local image = display.newImage( imagePath )
  image.x, image.y = x, y
  group:insert( image )

  -- add motion (if needed) --
  transition.to(image, {time=1000, x=display.contentWidth/2, y=0, transition=easing.inOutQuad})

  -- add Listener --
  image:addEventListener("touch", function() print("imageClicked") end )
end

local status = { myObject = myObject }

return status
```

**-- Gamemenu.lua --** (This is your game scene)

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

function scene:createScene( event )
  -- create a display group --
  local screenGroup = self.view

  settings.myObject(screenGroup, display.contentWidth/2, -(display.contentHeight/2), "bg.jpg")
  screenGroup:insert( bg )

  -- require object page --
  local settings = require "settings"

  -- call object --
  settings.myObject(screenGroup, 200, 100, "Icon.png")

end
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )

return scene
```

Keep Coding............ :)

Comment: I see you are using Director Class for this.  As my game already uses Storyboard, is it possible to do it with Storyboard rather than Director Class?  Are there any issues with using a mix of Director Class for some scene transitions and Storyboard for others?  Director Class is no longer being supported, so I'd prefer to use Storyboard throughout.

Comment: @Teevus: Hi, You can do that with 'Storyboard' too. For that, I've updated the above code(see) . And, what do you mean by 'the director class is no longer supported'..!!!

Comment: I just mean that the last update to Director Class was Aug 26, 2011, so it does not appear to be actively maintained.

Comment: I had issues getting the above code to work - runtime errors on a few lines including:settings.myObject(screenGroup, display.contentWidth/2, -(display.contentHeight/2), "bg.jpg")

Comment: Make sure that you have the image named 'bg.jpg' in the same folder where your 'main.lua' exists.